# Check if device is connected to i-net

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection, 3g

In need to check if the phone is connected to the internet.

I currently implemented this check as followed:

```
NSString *connectionString = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/ncr"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

//If user isn't connected
if ([connectionString length] == 0){
    //Do this
} else {
    //Do that
}
```

This check works perfectly on WIFI networks! But as soon as the user is on a 3G / EDGE network the connectionString = null

How can I improve this check, even on 3G networks?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has made a great class for doing this: [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

It can tell you wether you are connect to WiFi or WAN (3G and GRPS).

Comment: I imported Reachability.h/.m into my project.

Comment: And I implemented updatedInterfaceWithReachability and reachabilityChanged.

Comment: But where and how can I check, if the user IS connected to the internet, regardless if its over WIFI or 3G?